# Filter a request from a API in javascript

Tags: javascript

I started to study JavaScript has little time and I have a project that generates a random movie from imdb, but I need to filter adult content from a response that the API (omdb) provides

sometimes he provides me with an adult movie and in api's response I can see the following variables

adult: true or false

I would like to take this response from api and if it is true to re-run the function

something like that

if (adult = true) run again the function

```
<pre>

function rsandom(){

var id = [];
    movieId = id
  axios.get('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/'+movieId+'?api_key=xxx')
.then((response) => {
  console.log(response);
  let movie = response.data;
     if (adult = true){
         $("#Random").click() //its a buttom that runs my function rsandom
        }

</pre>
```

but it's not working. I should do this "error handling" out of my function? or otherwise?

I hope you understood me, I'm new in this area and I'm enjoying learning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of issues in your code, I think. You need a closing paren on the .then function. Also, you need to look at the data in the `console.log(response.data)` if it is an array, you'll need to loop through the data (or a higher order function, ie: .filter, .map, .reduce) and check each index. You'll need to move your jquery out of the .then to trigger it, or else it will run recursively, and you might cause something to break if you do that. You're pretty close if you return the movie to another variable, or handle your login in your .then.

Keep it up, you're almost there!

```
function rsandom(){
  var id = [];
  movieId = id
  let movie = {}
  axios.get('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/'+movieId+'?api_key=xxx')
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
      movie = response.data;  
      return movie;
  });// returns an obj or an array

  if (adult = true){
     $("#Random").on('click', rsandom) //its a buttom that runs my function rsandom
  }
```

Comment: Thank you friend! I'll try here